# showing NAN values for strings in dataframe when i tried to load sql tabel in to dataframe

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

I have  a table in SQL and I've tried to extract that table data into a 
    data frame, when I tried to print data frames it is showing numbers 
    perfectly when coming to string values it is displaying as "NAN"

```
import pymysql``
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

storage = input("Enter your database name :")
table = input("Enter your table name")
db = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', database=storage, user='', 
passwd='')
cursor = db.cursor()
print("Connected to " + storage)

query = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM ' +table , db)

df = DataFrame(query, columns=['First_name', 'Last_name ', 'Age', 'SEX', 
'Income', 'Cellno', 'Id', 'Aadhar'])

print(df)
```

Instead of printing values, it is printing NAN for columns (first_name, 
    Last_name, age, income,)

I've tried my best to solve this but didn't get any result

```
storage = input("Enter your database name :")
table = input("Enter your table name")
db = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', database=storage, user='', 
passwd='')
cursor = db.cursor()
print("Connected to " + storage)

query = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM ' +table , db)

df = DataFrame(query, columns=['First_name', 'Last_name ', 'Age', 'SEX', 
'Income', 'Cellno', 'Id', 'Aadhar'])
print(df)
```

Instead of printing values, it is still printing NAN for columns (first_name, 
    Last_name, age, income,)

Comment: Have you tried pd.read_sql?  This method will generate a dataframe directly from the sql query.  You can rename columns after.  This should pull everything, including column names directly into the dataframe.  If you're still getting nulls i'd check the database data.

```df = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM ' +table , db)```

Comment: Hey, It worked by using pd.read_sql, Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using another package is ok for you, try `psycopg2` and this pattern

```
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2

host = 'host_name'
database = 'database_name'
username = 'username'
password = 'password'

storage = input("Enter your database name :")
table = input("Enter your table name")

    with psycopg2.connect(f"host='{host}' 
                            dbname='{database}' 
                            user='{username}' 
                            password='{password}'") as connection:
        sqlQuery = """
SELECT * FROM %s' %(table)
"""
        data = pd.read_sql(sqlQuery, connection)
```